# MULE how to calculate number of days between two dates in dataweave

Tags: json, date, mule, dataweave

I have two dates in JSON response 
"startDate": "2017-04-30",
"EndDate": "2017-05-27",

they are transformed in dataweave as dates. I need to calculate number of days between those two dates. Is there any function in dataweave to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation is to use MEL Global Function and utilize  `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate.toInstant(), endDate.toInstant())`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
  {
     "diff": ((payload.start_date as :date) - (payload.end_date as :date)).days
   }
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This also returns 27 days if you use 30 march as the start date.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer by @Dinesh ,
The returned object from subtracting dates is a duration object which you can perform different methods on it.
More about [Duration class](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Duration.html)

Answer (score 0):

%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun getDiffDays(date1: String, date2: String) = ( (date1 as Date) - (date2 as Date)).days

---

{

```
"diff4":        getDiffDays("2021-10-04", "2020-10-04"),
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).